# Sorting of String Column in Gridview ASPx Page

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

[image]

I have applied Dataview Sort on Sno Column but it is not sorting properly, Sno is as a string i am really stuck with it help please?

Comment: First sort the column by using `order by` and then bind data to `gridview`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the **Sorting** event. Kindly check [this example on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting?view=netframework-4.8).